How to delete a project from intellij idea on mac 2024.1.4?
unable to delete project from IntelliJ idea.
even after deleting from recent projects and closing the project.
how to remove it from the Intellij idea without touching the project source code. and I want to re import the project.

First of all, I closed the project.
-> file -> close project.
then I removed it from recent projects on the welcome screen of IntelliJ Idea.
after that, I opened the finder and moved to the project location.
Then, opened a terminal window at the project location.
assume the project path /documents/project/.
and performed the below commands to delete .idea and its subdirectories.
ls -a
rm -rf .idea
